# Windows command for file size only

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a Windows command that will output the size in bytes of a specified file like this?

```
> filesize test.jpg
65212
```

I know that the [`dir`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) command outputs this information, but it outputs other information also.

I could easily write such a program, but I would prefer to use a native Windows command if possible, or only what is available in a fresh install of Windows XP.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you are inside a batch script, you can use argument variable tricks to get the filesize:

filesize.bat:

```
@echo off
echo %~z1
```

This gives results like the ones you suggest in your question.

Type

```
help call
```

at the command prompt for all of the crazy variable manipulation options. Also see [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/11/20/top-10-dos-batch-tips-yes-dos-batch.aspx) for more information.

**Edit:**
This only works in Windows 2000 and later

Comment: Note, this will only work for one file. If you want to be able to pass in a mask to get the sizes of multiple files, change the second line to something like `for %%I in (%1) do @echo %%~znI`.

Comment: @Mike, But what's the command to count the number of bytes of the channeled stdout? (as opposed to saved file)

Comment: @Pacerier, not sure if that's possible using this method. The %~z variables refer specifically to a file passed as an argument, so will be looking up their values from the filesystem, rather than a dynamic stream of bytes.

Comment: Don't derp like me and combine the answer's batch with Patrick Cuff's comment. I was going crazy trying to figure out why `for %I in (file.ext) do @echo %~zn1` wasn't working in a console (`1 != I` xD)

Answer (score 49):

If you don't want to do this in a batch script, you can do this from the command line like this:

```
for %I in (test.jpg) do @echo %~zI
```

Ugly, but it works. You can also pass in a file mask to get a listing for more than one file:

```
for %I in (*.doc) do @echo %~znI
```

Will display the size, file name of each .DOC file.

Comment: Nice, I was wondering how to get that to work from the command line

Comment: any way to get file size in KB?

Answer (score 17):

Use a function to get rid off some limitation in the `~z` operator. It is especially useful with a `for` loop:

```
@echo off
set size=0
call :filesize "C:\backup\20120714-0035\error.log"
echo file size is %size%
goto :eof

:: Set filesize of first argument in %size% variable, and return
:filesize
  set size=%~z1
  exit /b 0
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! Is there a way to get %size% to show the size in Kilobytes instead of Bytes?

Comment: You may use the set /a operator :
set /a size=%~z1/1024

Answer (score 13):

Try [forfiles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx):

```
forfiles /p C:\Temp /m file1.txt /c "cmd /c echo @fsize"
```

The `forfiles` command runs command `c` for each file `m` in directory `p`.

The variable `@fsize` is replaced with the size of each file.

If the file `C:\Temp\file1.txt` is 27 bytes, `forfiles` runs this command:

```
cmd /c echo 27
```

Which prints `27` to the screen.

As a side-effect, it clears your screen as if you had run the `cls` command.

Answer (score 6):

Since you're using Windows XP, Windows PowerShell is an option.

```
(Get-Item filespec ).Length
```

or as a function

```
function Get-FileLength { (Get-Item $args).Length }
Get-FileLength filespec
```

Comment: ps: I don't think Powershell is included in a fresh install of XP. Unless you are imaging from a SP2 or later with Powershell already in there.

Answer (score 4):

Create a file named *filesize.cmd* (and put into folder *C:\Windows\System32*):

```
@echo %~z1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
C:\>FORFILES  /C "cmd /c echo @fname @fsize"


C:\>FORFILES  /?

FORFILES [/P pathname] [/M searchmask] [/S]
         [/C command] [/D [+ | -] {MM/dd/yyyy | dd}]

Description:
    Selects a file (or set of files) and executes a
    command on that file. This is helpful for batch jobs.

Parameter List:
    /P    pathname      Indicates the path to start searching.
                        The default folder is the current working
                        directory (.).
```

Comment: Note that this command wont provide directory size, even there is no ready made command available in windows. You have to write recursive script for that.

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell you can do:

```
$imageObj = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo("C:\test.jpg")    
$imageObj.Length
```

Comment: It will work, but it ignores all the built-in capabilities of PowerShell for common tasks

Comment: You'd rather use Get-ChildItem test.jpg | Select-Object Length in Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Taken [from here](http://windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/windows/excerpt/win_svr_ckbk/part1.html?page=2):

The following command finds folders that are greater than 100 MB in size on the D: drive:

```
diruse /s /m /q:100 /d d:
```

The /s option causes subdirectories to be searched, the /m option displays disk usage in megabytes, the /q:100 option causes folders that are greater than 100 MB to be marked, and the /d option displays only folders that exceed the threshold specified by /q.

Use the diskuse command to find files over a certain size. The following command displays files over 100 MB in size on the D: drive:

```
diskuse D: /x:104857600 /v /s
```

The /x:104857600 option causes files over 104,857,600 bytes to be displayed and is valid only if you include the /v option (verbose). The /s option means subdirectories from the specified path (in this case, the D: drive) are searched.

**Using VBScript**

```
' This code finds all files over a certain size.
' ------ SCRIPT CONFIGURATION ------
strComputer = "**<ServerName>**" 
intSizeBytes = 1024 * 1024 * 500  ' = 500 MB
' ------ END CONFIGURATION ---------
set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
set colFiles = objWMI.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from CIM_DataFile where FileSize > '" & intSizeBytes & "'")
for each objFile in colFiles
    Wscript.Echo objFile.Name & "  " & objFile.Filesize / 1024 / 1024 & "MB"
next
```

Answer (score 1):

In a batch file, the below works for local files, but fails for files on network hard drives

```
for %%I in ("test.jpg") do @set filesize=%~z1
```

However, it's inferior code, because it doesn't work for files saved on a network drive (for example, `\\Nas\test.jpg` and `\\192.168.2.40\test.jpg`). The below code works for files in any location, and I wrote it myself.

I'm sure there are more efficient ways of doing this using [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript), or PowerShell or whatever, but I didn't want to do any of that; good ol' batch for me!

```
set file=C:\Users\Admin\Documents\test.jpg
set /a filesize=
set fileExclPath=%file:*\=%

:onemoretime
set fileExclPath2=%fileExclPath:*\=%
set fileExclPath=%fileExclPath2:*\=%
if /i "%fileExclPath%" NEQ "%fileExclPath2%" goto:onemoretime

dir /s /a-d "%workingdir%">"%temp%\temp.txt"
findstr /C:"%fileExclPath%" "%temp%\temp.txt" >"%temp%\temp2.txt"

set /p filesize= <"%temp%\temp2.txt"

echo set filesize=%%filesize: %fileExclPath%%ext%=%% >"%temp%\temp.bat"
call "%temp%\temp.bat"

:RemoveTrailingSpace
if /i "%filesize:~-1%" EQU " " set filesize=%filesize:~0,-1%
if /i "%filesize:~-1%" EQU " " goto:RemoveTrailingSpace

:onemoretime2
set filesize2=%filesize:* =%
set filesize=%filesize2:* =%
if /i "%filesize%" NEQ "%filesize2%" goto:onemoretime2

set filesize=%filesize:,=%
echo %filesize% bytes

SET /a filesizeMB=%filesize%/1024/1024
echo %filesizeMB% MB

SET /a filesizeGB=%filesize%/1024/1024/1024
echo %filesizeGB% GB
```

Comment: I suspect the example you gave should be: for %%I in ("test.jpg") do @set filesize=%%~zI

Answer (score 1):

wmic datafile where name='c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe' get filesize /format:value

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell  you *should* do this:

```
(Get-ChildItem C:\TEMP\file1.txt).Length
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you were asking about and it can only be used from the command line (and may be useless in a batch file), but one quick way to check file size is just to use `dir`:

```
> dir Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.xml
```

Results in:

```
Directory of C:\PathToTheFile

08/10/2015  10:57 AM         2,905,897 Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.xml
               1 File(s)      2,905,897 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  759,192,064,000 bytes free
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about remote ones, but for local Windows trough {File Sharing / Network}, `%~z` does work

```
for %%x in ("\\ComputerName\temp\temp.txt") do set "size=%%~zx"
```

More generalized version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37495552/12669337) . The previous version may be not requiring `enableDelayedExpansion enableExtensions`, but can't run in `for` loops .

- Some clarification --

  - `|` can't be used to pass an output value to `set` ; `for /f` doesn't support some characters in it's subject value (the path to edit), if without in-text Escaping ; `for /l` doesn't allow to change the count/condition values (after start) ; `!<<variableName>>:<<escaped text>>*!` doesn't work .
  - at keepOnlyAllBefore1stSpace, `%%%%x` is passed instead of `!nu_f!`, because that is needed for  the same reason/use as `%%%%x` is made to be created .

```
@setLocal enableDelayedExpansion enableExtensions
@echo off

set "file=C:\Users\Admin\Documents\test.jpg"

for %%x in ("!file!") do set "name=%%~nxx"
for %%x in ("!file!") do set "storage=%%~pdx"
    set "storage=!storage:~0,-1!"

dir "!storage!" > "!temp!\fileInfo.txt"

findstr /c:"!name!" "!temp!\fileInfo.txt" > "!temp!\fileInfo_1.txt"
    del "!temp!\fileInfo.txt"
set /p "size=" < "!temp!\fileInfo_1.txt"
    del "!temp!\fileInfo_1.txt"

call :for 1 2 "call :deleteCollumnFromStart size"

call :for 1 1 "call :keepOnlyAllBefore1stSpace %%%%x size"

:removeSpacesFromEnd
    if /i "!size:~-1!" equ " " set "size=!size:~0,-1!"
    if /i "!size:~-1!" equ " " goto removeSpacesFromEnd

echo(!size:,= ! bytes

pause
exit /b


:deleteCollumnFromStart
    set "%~1=!%~1:* =!"
    :removeAllSpacesFromStart
        if /i "!%~1:~0,1!" equ " " set "%~1=!%~1:~1!"
        if /i "!%~1:~0,1!" equ " " goto removeAllSpacesFromStart
goto :eof

:keepOnlyAllBefore1stSpace
    if /i "!%~2:~%~1,1!" equ " " (
        set "%~2=!%~2:~0,%~1!"
    ) else (
        set /a "nu1_f= !nu1_f! + 1"
    )
goto :eof

:for
    set "nu_f=%~1"
    set "nu1_f=%~2"
    :f_repeatTimes
        if not !nu1_f! lss !nu_f! (
            rem echo(f_repeatTimes !nu_f! !nu1_f! %*
            for %%x in (!nu_f!) do (
                %~3
            )
            set /a "nu_f= !nu_f! + 1"
            goto f_repeatTimes
        )
goto :eof
```