# How does a Windows batch file detect that a file is > 0 bytes?

Tags: batch-file

I have a Windows batch file utilized in my Visual Studio tool chain that creates a list of files in a particular directory, and then uses "findstr" to narrow this list down to only the files whose names contain a particular string; and then does some work on these files.

```
dir /b \mypath\*.wav >wavRawList.txt

findstr /b /v "DesiredString" wavRawList.txt >wavListWithDesiredString.txt

for /f %%a in (wavListWithDesiredString.txt) do (

  [... do some stuff ...]

)
```

Visual Studio frequently reports errors from this batch file, and I think it's because wavListWithDesiredString.txt frequently ends up being a file with a length of 0.  Is there a variety of "if exist wavListWithDesiredString.txt" where instead of "exist" I can substitute a command meaning "if it exists and its file length is greater than 0"?

Answer (score 7):

The more-or-less inline way, using `for`:

```
for %%x in (wavListWithDesiredString.txt) do if not %%~zx==0 (
    ...
)
```

or you can use a subroutine:

```
:size
set SIZE=%~z1
goto :eof
```

which you can call like this:

```
call :size wavListWithDesiredString.txt
if not %SIZE%==0 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IF EXIST %1 IF %~z1 GTR 0 ECHO Both conditions are satisfied.
```

Does not work, because if file does not exist this part:
"IF %~z1 GTR 0" resolves to "IF  GTR 0" which is invalid command and results in:

```
0 was unexpected at this time.
```

Delayed expansion does not help either. To fix use this:

```
if exist %1 (
    echo "Ouput file exists, checking size"
    for %%x in (%1) do if not %%~zx==0 (
        echo "File exists, size is non zero"
        ... DO SOMETHING ...
    ) else (
        echo "Size is zero"
    )
) else (
    echo "There is no file"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the file size part of the question with [another stack overflow question found here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/483864/299327). I would use nesting to simulate the AND operator like the example below:

```
IF EXIST %1 IF %~z1 GTR 0 ECHO Both conditions are satisfied.
```

The %1 is a parameter that must be passed into a batch file.