# SVN ignore large files

Tags: svn, svnignore

I'm trying to get svn to ignore got large datafiles in a directory. Since all the files in the directory share the same extention, specifying a pattern in svn:ignore doesn't do. Is there a way to say "ignore files larger than N MiB"?

Comment: Why would you want to only exclude large files of a type and not other ones? Doesn't that counter the idea of having a complete, consistent and revisioned copy of your project? Normally I exclude only files that are generated or external from the SVN tree.

Comment: Yes it does, but my repository is limited in size, so I need to commit sparingly. Besides, these are datafiles and they never really change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a list of the files you want to ignore (possibly using an OS tool such as find on Linux) and then do something like this:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "*" --targets filelist.txt
```

Comment: Not really what the OP is asking for: `"ignore files larger than N MiB"?`, perhaps the specific files can change and they're after a more general solution to ignoring large files? =)

Comment: The svn propset command does not have a built in ability to filter based on file size.  Without information about what other tools the OP has available I believe this is the most general solution other than manually issuing a series of svn propset commands.  The filelist.txt file can be editted/regenerated as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially I would write a commandline script that iterates over all files of the desired filetype and than executes the `svn propset` command mentioned by @ChrisH if the filesize is bigger than the boundary you define.

If your on Windows [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483864/windows-command-for-file-size-only) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Put a list of the files you want to ignore (possibly using an OS tool such as find on Linux) and then do something like this:
>
> ```
> svn propset svn:ignore "*" --targets filelist.txt
> ```

If you take @ChrisH's answer and combine it with a pre-commit hook, that should solve the problem.

Using the amazing guide [here](http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook), write a pre-commit hook that filters each file using the command referenced by @Johannes Wachter.