# How can I find the file size only using the windows command shell?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, filesize

I'm trying to write a script that checks if the size of a file is greater than 0 and if so, prints "greater".  I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483864/windows-command-for-file-size-only) question and got some good ideas. I tried to implement what the second answerer answered, but it's not working properly.

This is what I have so far:

```
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
set size=0
set /A size=%%~zi
echo %%i %size%
if %size% GTR 0 echo greater
)
```

When I try this, it keeps giving me the same size for all the files, even though I know that one of them is different. When I remove the `set size=0`, if the file size is 0, it gives an error `0 was unexpected at this time.`

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try this command:

```
for %%I in (*.txt) do @echo %%~znI
```

When I run this, I get the following result on Windows 7:

```
C:\Users\Leniel\Desktop>for %I in (*.txt) do @echo %~znI
14 test1
34 test2
```

where 14 and 34 is the file size in bytes...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an actual environment variable inside that `for` block, you need delayed expansion:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%i in (*.txt) do (
  set size=0
  set /A size=%%~zi
  echo %%i !size!
  if !size! GTR 0 echo greater
)
```

Note also that you need to replace `%size%` by `!size!` to trigger delayed expansion instead of the normal one.

The problem is that normal environment variables are expanded when a statement is *parsed*; the `for` block is a single statement in that regard. So once the loop runs the value of `size` from *before* the loop is used.

Delayed expansion (with `!`) will expand the variables right before execution instead of when a statement is parsed so you will see the updated value from within the loop.

Answer (score 1):

robocopy /L (dir you want the size of) (C:\arbitrary folder) *.* /Log:(C:\arbitrary folder\robolog.txt)

That wil create a document that has the size
findstr Bytes C:\robocopylog.txt >>getsize.txt

You can use For /? to help navigate to the last entry of getsize.txt which should contain the size of the entire directory. 
You will have to handle whether it is k for Kilo m for mega bytes or g for Gigs Which can be solved since robocopy uses 0 as place holders so you would only need to get the 3rd and 4th token of the last line. 514.46 m

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this caused the problem, but this code worked.

```
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
echo %%i %%~zi
echo %%~zi
if %%~zi GTR 0 echo greater
)
```

I think it had to do with when the %size% variable was getting replaced and reset. I'd still like to replace the `%%~zi` with a variable name, but I think I'll leave it if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it in PowerShell. I hope it convinces you to upgrade to a more modern shell:

```
PS C:\test> Get-ChildItem *.txt | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.name, $_.length }
test.txt 16
test2.txt 5
```