# How to check the size of a file from command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement

I need to be able to check a files filesize, and then do an if statement in a batch file

e.g. if file < 20KB start notepad, if > 20KB start wordpad

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows command for file size only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483864/windows-command-for-file-size-only)

Comment: @Michael Burr No, this requires if statements as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
if exist "%~f1" (
    if %~z1 GEQ 20480 (
        start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe" "%~f1"
    ) else (
        start notepad "%~f1"
    )
)
```

**Edit:** The %~z syntax only works for parameters and FOR loops, for a hardcoded name you can use a helper function:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
goto main

:getfilesize 
set %1=0
if exist "%~f2" set %1=%~z2
@goto :EOF

:main
set myfile=test.txt
call :getfilesize mysize "%myfile%"
if %mysize% GEQ 20480 (
    start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe" "%myfile%"
) else (
    start notepad "%myfile%"
)
```

Comment: I would like to enter it e.g. it checks a predefined file to see if its 20kb or not

Comment: @James: I just used %1 (The first parameter) in the sample code (Yourbatch.cmd yourfile.txt)