# Check local-file size before uploading to FTP (Batch File)

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I am developing an batch file, that will read all files of extension .dem, and will upload it to my FTP.
However, only files with more than 1mb can be uploaded.

My current script is:

(upload_demos.ftp)

> open my_ip
>
> username
>
> pass
>
> lcd /D "C:\TF2_Server\tf"
>
> cd  SourceTV/
>
> binary
>
> mput *.dem
>
> disconnect
>
> quit

And (move_demo_to_ftp.bat)

> ftp -i -s:upload_demos.ftp
>
> cd C:\TF2_Server\tf
>
> del /S *.dem

With these scripts, all *.dem files will be uploaded (Including those with size less than 1mb ).

Can you guys help me check the file-size before uploading (And deleting ? )

Thank you,

Comment: Is any `.dem` file larger than 1.999 GB?

Comment: maybe you could consider using `winscp` for scripting this? It has many useful options, filtering by filesize included: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask

Answer (score 0):

To display the size of a certain file you can use the trick already explained in this question: [Windows command for file size only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483864/windows-command-for-file-size-only)
Then, you can integrate that external `.bat` file in a `for` cycle to set the output of a `dir /b /a-d` command as a variable and so to be sent to the external `.bat` file.
Here is the example:

> for /f "delims=^T" %%g in ('dir /b /a-d') do (call file_dimension.bat
>   %%g)

You can also set an `if` statement inside the `for` cycle to check if the dimension of the file is less, equal or greater than a certain value.