# How to get to know the (bit) size of an output in jupyter notebook cell?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, size, jupyter

How could I get to know how large is an output of sime code which is shown in the cell of Jupyter ntb cell? Eg., if I have a plot:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

sns.heatmap(np.arange(50).reshape(5,-1))
```

the size of the ntb file is 14 KB and using this approach I could determine the size without the output and/or always look at one cell (copy it out). But what if I want to know this from within the ntb? Ie how much space the output takes.

To be clear, I do not care about the actual size of the object, ie if I print an array, I do not care how much that array takes up, but rather how much takes up the text which is being printed out, by how much will the `.ipynb` file grow.

Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you interested in the size of a notebook file? And running  `!ls -alth <notebook.ipynb>` and parsing the output might do the trick.

Comment: :) both out of curiosity and I that have a file which I need to keep below some size and since I have plots there and if I would need to remove some so that I know which to remove/hide. Because I would want to hide as least as possible but enough. BTW that does not work for me, at least not in Windows (gives that `ls` is not recognised, need to be with `%`)

Comment: `ls` is a unix command. So it will not work on a windows shell. Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483864/windows-command-for-file-size-only) discussion can be useful. Sorry! I don't have a windows machine to test it out.

Comment: Ah, I see now where the problem is - we speak about different things. `%ls -alth <notebook.ipynb>` works fine for me but gives me the size of the file, not of an individual cell/output of a cell in jupyter.

Comment: Run it before and after a cell and subtract the sizes :-)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did not want to do and wanted to avoid :D. That is the point of the question, if that is possible to do from within jupyter or without this quite expensive "cheat"

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104080/how-can-i-check-file-size-in-python